# Which is the fastest way to create million rows of INSERT script?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-insert

I want to copy specific column data from one different table to another different table to create as INSERT SCRIPT.So for i tried with Excel but its time consuming and confusing a lot because daily i have to create milliion rows of insert script.I too experiment with SQL developer tool inbulit INSERT export, but can't get as required. If anyone knows quick and efficient method please let me know.Am fresher to DB.

Note:

1. Using SQL developer tool
2. Using Oracle 12c

Comment: I want to create SCRIPT, because it will be moved to production team for deployemnt. So i cant use this ```insert into table2 select * from table1;```

Comment: You'll be **not lucky** with a script with *million rows*. As your DBA if there is a DB LINK from prod to your environment - than you could use `INSERT`. Otheriwise consider some sort of export / import.

Comment: Ok i will look into it@MarmiteBomber

Comment: @Nvr What went wrong with SQL Developer creating the file? It should be able to handle this task quickly.

Comment: @JonHeller I cant choose needed column in SQL developer export.That is the problem am facing

Comment: @Nvr Do you have the ability to create a view and edit the text file? You could create a view using only the relevant columns, and then export the view. The export file would target the view, but that could be fixed with a simple find and replace "Insert into your_view" with "Insert into your_table".

Answer (score -1):

This is Oracle.

To make it simple:

```
insert into table2 select * from table1;
```

That's all. Why would you want to do it row-by-row, in a million separate `INSERT` statements? That's probably the *worst* option you can choose.

Answer (score -1):

Why not try as

```
INSERT INTO table_two
   SELECT COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B FROM table_one;

COMMIT:
```

If you have any where condition, add onto the select statement.

Answer (score -1):

Well, as you are asking the fastest way to do it, nothing like direct path

```
insert /*+append */ into table2 select * from table1 ;
```

Answer (score -1):

why dont you create view from table 1?

```
create view table2 (col1, col2) as select col1, col2 from table1 where col3=x;
```